# Native options for obscuring/encrypting a string?

Tags: javascript, string, encryption

As an exercise, I've been working on replicating [this game](http://enigmadevice.com). In case it becomes inaccessible, the premise of the game is to take a quote that's been scrambled by swapping pairs of letters (eg replace A with M and vice versa), and unscramble it to its original arrangement.

As I'm studying this game, I realize it's almost trivial to extract the solution from the source - there are any number of breakpoints you can place to access it. I've been trying to come up with a way to obscure the string in a way that it isn't immediately accessible, and the only thing I can think of is some kind of native obscuring function before the quote even has a chance to land in a variable. Something like this:

```
var litmus, quotes = [
    "String One",
    "String Two",
    ....
    "String n",
];

litmus = obscureString(quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*(n-1))]);
```

This way the user can't summon up the raw quote, or even the random integer that was used - they're gone by the time the breakpoint hits.

My question is this: is there any kind of native function that would fit the role of `obscureString()` in the above example, even loosely? I'm aware JavaScript doesn't have any native encryption/hash methods, and any [libraries](http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html) that provide that functionality just provide a chance to drop a breakpoint. Thus, I'm hoping someone here can come up with a creative way to natively obscure a string, if it's even possible in JS.

Comment: what'd prevent someone from simplly calling your "revealString()" from the debug console to extract the answer?

Comment: @MarcB The idea is to take the user's guess and pass it through the same obfuscation, then compare the result against the litmus to test an answer.

Comment: in which case you'd probably want a hash function, so that the "obscured" string can't be decoded/revealed anymore, e.g. dig up an sha1() implementation for javascript.

Comment: @MarcB my thoughts as well, but adding a library defeats the purpose - the user can just drop a breakpoint in that encryption function and retrieve the raw from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been crunching on it for a while, and I found a *very* makeshift solution.

The only native (read: non-user-corruptible) transformation/hash function I was able to find was `window.btoa`. It does exactly what I need, in letting me obscure a string before the user ever has a chance to get their hands on it. The problem, however, is that it has a counterpart `window.atob`, whose only purpose is to reverse the process.

To solve that, I was able to neutralize `window.atob` with the following line of code, essentially making `window.btoa` a one-way trip:

```
window.atob = function(f){ return f; };
```

**Don't make a habit of this.**

This is ***horrific*** practice, and I feel dirty for writing it. It's passable in this case because my application is small, self-contained, and won't ever need to rely on that function elsewhere - but I can't in good conscience recommend this as a general solution. Many browsers won't even let you override native functions in the first place.

Just wanted to post the answer in case someone found themselves in a similar situation needing a similar answer - this may be the closest we can get to a one-way native hash function for now.

Comment: It should be noted that a clever user can just override `window.bota` in this manner as well, taking the obfuscation out of the question. This shouldn't be relied upon for any kind of actual security - it just makes it a pain in the ass for would-be meddlers.